# How to join multiple SQL tables on column that is only in some of them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for an elegant solution (in terms of query length / maintainability) to the following problem:

I have 10 SQL tables, each with different columns (up to 50 columns per table). Each table has an "ID" column (name differs from table to table) that serves as an identifier.

I want to join the tables in a way so that each distinct ID has one row with data from all tables where this ID is found. The problem is, I don't know in which table(s) a match will be found, if at all.

- **Example 1**: Row #1 from table 10 matches a row in tables 1, 2, and 3.
- **Example 2**: Row #2 from table 10 matches a row in tables 2, 7, and 8.
- **Example 3**: Row #3 from table 10 matches a row in table 6.
- **Example 4**: Row #4 from table 10 has no match in any of the tables.
- etc.

If I just chain OUTER JOINs like this:

```
SELECT
    --List all desired columns here
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN table3 ON table1.ID = table3.ID
...
FULL OUTER JOIN table10 ON table1.ID = table10.ID
```

then I think Example 2 and 3 will not be joined the way I want to.

**So how can I join each table on the first "ID" column that has some data from previous tables?**

Comment: What columns do you want?  Why doesn't your query work?  How can a "row" have no match in any of the tables?  I'm confused.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us understand your goal here, as it's unclear right now

Comment: Most likely OP has IDs 1,2 in first table, 2,3 in second, 3,4 in third and needs result, containing IDs 1,2,3,4.

Comment: What happens if you do `SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
FULL JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
...
FULL JOIN table10 AS t10 ON t9.ID = t10.ID` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, I get it.  You are correct.  In your form, if `table2.id` does not match any `table1.id`, then weird things happen.

In standard SQL, the fix would be simpler with `USING`.  Alas, SQL Server does not support `USING`.  Instead, use a bunch of `COALESCE()`s:

```
FROM table1 FULL JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.ID = table2.ID
     table3
     ON table3.ID = COALESCE(table1.ID, table2.ID) FULL JOIN
     . . .
     table10
     ON table10.ID = COALESCE(table1.ID, table2.ID, . . . , table9.ID)
```